# Exponential function, domain of definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exponential-function

I have the function $\displaystyle f(x,y)=x^2e^{-x^2-y^2}$ with the domain of definition = $\{(x,y) \mid x^2+y^2=2\}$

The task is to decide $f$'s maximum and minimum value and the range. How do I get there?

Comment: As you're using a multivariable calculus tag, you're likely going to use derivatives. Perhaps even lagrange multipliers. Do these sound familiar?

Comment: Not clear what `(x,y)x,x^2+y^2=2` means. Do you mean $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=2\}$?

Comment: yes they sound familiar to me but I don´t know how to solve these kind of questions. Please help me! @mixedmath

Comment: Derivatives are overkill if Thomas's interpretation is correct.

Comment: yes exactly! @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Comment: what´s that? please show me

Answer (score 1):

For $(x,y) \in A=\{(x,y) |x^2+y^2=2\}$ you have:

$$f(x,y)=x^2e^{-x^2-y^2}=x^2e^{-(x^2+y^2)}=x^2e^{-2}$$

so $f(x,y)$ is maximal when $x^2$ is maximal, so for $(\sqrt{2},0)$ and $(-\sqrt{2},0)$.